# MySQL - stored procedure not returning resultset

Tags: mysql

I created a procedure on MySQL 5.5.22-Ubuntu, and on my test it should return four rows but it is not returning anything. I already read it would be difficult to return a resultset and I tried a few approaches but none worked (as select... into @result...).
Also, I tried to run the select out of the procedure, and it is returning, but when I run through the procedure, it just doesn't return anything. Could anyone please assist me?

See below my procedure code:

```
DELIMITER $$


DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `switchboard3b-scheduler`.`getCurrentAndNextScheduleItem`$$ 



CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getCurrentAndNextScheduleItem`(IN screenId int, IN scheduleId int 

-- , OUT cursorScheduleItems int

)

BEGIN

-- select current item

 -- declare cursorScheduleItems cursor for 

(SELECT "CURRENT_ITEM" as "ITEM", si.id,si.start_time,si.end_time, si.play_through, c.filename,ct.command 

FROM schedule_item si JOIN channel_content cc ON si.channel_content_id = cc.id 

    JOIN content c ON cc.content_id = c.id 

    JOIN content_type ct ON c.content_type_id = ct.id 

WHERE si.channel_screen_id = @screenId 

    AND si.schedule_id = @scheduleId

    AND (si.day=0 OR si.day=DAYOFWEEK(DATE(NOW()))) 

    AND si.start_time <= NOW() 

    AND si.end_time > NOW() 

ORDER BY si.day DESC, si.start_time DESC LIMIT 1)

-- select next item for that day

UNION ALL

(SELECT "NEXT_ITEM_TODAY" as "ITEM", si.id,si.start_time,si.end_time, si.play_through, c.filename,ct.command 

FROM schedule_item si JOIN channel_content cc ON si.channel_content_id = cc.id 

    JOIN content c ON cc.content_id = c.id 

    JOIN content_type ct ON c.content_type_id = ct.id 

WHERE si.channel_screen_id = @screenId 

    AND si.schedule_id = @scheduleId

    AND (si.day=0 OR si.day=DAYOFWEEK(DATE(NOW()))) 

    AND si.start_time > NOW()

ORDER BY si.day DESC, si.start_time ASC LIMIT 1)

-- select first two items of the next day

UNION ALL

(SELECT "NEXT_ITEMS_TOMORROW" as "ITEM", si.id,si.start_time,si.end_time, si.play_through, c.filename,ct.command 

FROM schedule_item si JOIN channel_content cc ON si.channel_content_id = cc.id 

    JOIN content c ON cc.content_id = c.id 

    JOIN content_type ct ON c.content_type_id = ct.id 

WHERE si.channel_screen_id = @screenId 

    AND si.schedule_id = @scheduleId

    AND (si.day=0 OR si.day=DAYOFWEEK(DATE(NOW()+1)))

ORDER BY si.day DESC,si.start_time ASC LIMIT 2);

-- CLOSE cursorScheduleItems;

END $$



DELIMITER ;
```

I tried to call it with the command:

```
CALL getCurrentAndNextScheduleItem(1,4);
```

Any tip would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to return? its type is not mentioned in the create procedure.

Comment: I'm trying to return a result set.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your "out" parameter is commented with --

```
-- , OUT cursorScheduleItems int
```